EyeDropper API is not working in Javascript Extension for Google Chrome
So I was trying to build a chrome extension just like Colorzilla that picks up colors from the web. I have implemented EyeDropper API which is experimental.
This is my popup.js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const btn = document.querySelector('.changeColorBtn');
    const colorGrid = document.querySelector('.colorGrid');
    const colorValue = document.querySelector('.colorValue');

    btn.addEventListener('click', async () => {
        let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });

        chrome.scripting.executeScript(
            {
                target: { tabId: tab.id },
                function: pickColor,
            },
            (injectionResults) => {
                const [data] = injectionResults;
                if (data && data.result) {
                    const color = data.result.sRGBHex;
                    colorGrid.style.backgroundColor = color;
                    colorValue.innerText = color;
                    try {
                        navigator.clipboard.writeText(color);
                    } catch (err) {
                        console.error('Failed to copy color to clipboard', err);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.error('No color picked');
                }
            }
        );
    });
});

async function pickColor() {
    try {
        const eyeDropper = new EyeDropper();
        return await eyeDropper.open();
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('EyeDropper failed: ', err);
        return { sRGBHex: null };  // Return a fallback value
    }
}

Error handling response: TypeError: injectionResults is not iterable
The extension console is showing this error everytime
I don't understand where I am wrong.  Is the code not working or EyeDropper API?
I was trying to implement EyeDropper API but it's not working

The error is not about the EyeDropper API, it's about injectionResults, which is not an array. It may be a bug in Chrome or you look at an old error in chrome://extensions page, which you can remove by clicking the button next to it. Use devtools to debug the code. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.
